# mismatch type between method with a generic parameter

Tags: java

I've got a weird problem that I can't seem to be able to solve. 
I've written a class that contains a map of generic type T that extends comperable. (the keys of the map are of type T and the items Integers)
one of the methods in the class has the following signature:

```
public int getCountForItem(T item)
```

I'm trying to implement a comperator for my class, that should use this function.
which has the following method:

```
public int compare(T o1, T o2)
```

However, when inside the method, I am trying to call getCountForItem, I get a compilation error, that there is a type mismatch.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

edit: this is all in java

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question.

Comment: "map of generic type T that extends comperable" `Comparable`? Or `Comparable<T>`?

Comment: try toCompare() Method if you are implementing Comparable interface.

Answer (score 1):

if your are using `public int compare(T o1, T o2)` method ,you should extend Comparator not Comparable.
compare() method is in Comparator Interface.